# PHP MySQL Search Form with equal range of number

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm trying to make a search form of lottery games.
My intention is that the form find all games where 12 of the 15 numbers drawn are equal.

I made a form, but does not work because it is displaying all the games that contains at least 1 successful outcome.

I want to appear only games where the match 12 numbers in every draw.

sql file contains only two rows id and numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lotto_table` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `numbers` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `lotto_table`
--

INSERT INTO `lotto_table` (`id`, `numbers`) VALUES
(3, '01, 04, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 20, 23, 24'),
(4, '01, 02, 04, 05, 08, 10, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 23, 24, 25'),
(5, '01, 02, 04, 08, 09, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20, 23, 24, 25'),
(6, '01, 02, 04, 05, 06, 07, 10, 12, 15, 16, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25'),
(7, '01, 04, 07, 08, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25'),
(8, '01, 05, 06, 08, 09, 10, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 25'),
(9, '03, 04, 05, 09, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 24, 25'),
(10, '02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 14, 19, 20, 23, 24'),
(11, '02, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 16, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25'),
(12, '01, 02, 04, 05, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 24, 25'),
(13, '03, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 23'),
(14, '01, 02, 05, 06, 07, 09, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25'),
(15, '01, 02, 04, 06, 08, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25'),
(16, '02, 05, 06, 07, 08, 10, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25'),
(17, '01, 02, 03, 05, 06, 07, 09, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21'),
(18, '02, 06, 07, 08, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24'),
(19, '02, 05, 06, 07, 08, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 23, 24'),
(20, '03, 04, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 23, 24'),
(21, '01, 02, 04, 05, 08, 11, 14, 16, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25'),
(22, '01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 09, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 22, 25'),
(23, '01, 03, 04, 05, 06, 08, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20'),
(24, '01, 02, 03, 05, 07, 10, 11, 14, 17, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25'),
(25, '01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 09, 13, 14, 16, 20, 22, 23, 24'),
(26, '05, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23'),
(27, '03, 06, 08, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25'),
(28, '01, 03, 07, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21'),
(29, '01, 04, 05, 06, 08, 09, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24'),
(30, '01, 02, 03, 04, 06, 07, 08, 11, 14, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23'),
(31, '01, 02, 03, 04, 09, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25'),
(32, '01, 02, 04, 06, 07, 09, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 22, 23'),
(33, '01, 02, 05, 07, 08, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24'),
(34, '01, 02, 04, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23'),
(35, '01, 04, 05, 06, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25'),
(36, '01, 04, 05, 07, 08, 10, 11, 14, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24'),
(37, '01, 03, 04, 05, 08, 09, 10, 11, 13, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24'),
(38, '01, 02, 03, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 22, 24, 25'),
(39, '02, 07, 08, 09, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24'),
(40, '01, 02, 05, 07, 08, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 24'),
(41, '02, 03, 04, 09, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25'),
(42, '01, 03, 04, 05, 06, 08, 11, 12, 14, 15, 17, 21, 22, 24, 25'),
(43, '01, 03, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 14, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24'),
(44, '03, 04, 05, 06, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 18, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25'),
(45, '01, 02, 03, 05, 07, 09, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25'),
(46, '01, 02, 04, 05, 06, 08, 10, 11, 14, 18, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25'),
(47, '01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 08, 10, 11, 13, 15, 18, 20, 22, 25'),
(48, '02, 05, 06, 07, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23'),
(49, '02, 04, 05, 06, 08, 11, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24'),
(50, '01, 02, 03, 06, 07, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25');
```

search form:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search the Database</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="search.php" method="post">
 Search:
 <input type="text" name="num1" />,
 <input type="text" name="num2" />,
 <input type="text" name="num3" />,
 <input type="text" name="num4" />,
 <input type="text" name="num5" />,
 <input type="text" name="num6" />,
 <input type="text" name="num7" />,
 <input type="text" name="num8" />,
 <input type="text" name="num9" />,
 <input type="text" name="num10" />,
 <input type="text" name="num11" />,
 <input type="text" name="num12" />,<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the number sequence is important, maybe better to put each number with one id in different columns as following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lotto_table` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `n1` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `n2` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `n3` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `n4` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `n5` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `n6` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `n7` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `n8` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `n9` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `n10` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `n11` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `n12` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `n13` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `n14` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `n15` int(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4
```

and then put the data:

```
INSERT INTO `lotto_table` (`n1`,`n2`,`n3`,`n4`,`n5`,`n6`,`n7`,`n8`,`n9`,`n10`,`n11`,`n12`,`n13`,`n14`,`n15`) 
VALUES
(01, 04, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 20, 23, 24),
(01, 02, 04, 05, 08, 10, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 23, 24, 25),
(01, 02, 04, 08, 09, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20, 23, 24, 25),
(01, 02, 04, 05, 06, 07, 10, 12, 15, 16, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25),
(01, 04, 07, 08, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25),
(01, 05, 06, 08, 09, 10, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 25),
(03, 04, 05, 09, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 24, 25),
(02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 14, 19, 20, 23, 24),
(02, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 16, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25),
(01, 02, 04, 05, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 24, 25),
(03, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 23),
(01, 02, 05, 06, 07, 09, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25),
(01, 02, 04, 06, 08, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25),
(02, 05, 06, 07, 08, 10, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25),
(01, 02, 03, 05, 06, 07, 09, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21),
(02, 06, 07, 08, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24),
(02, 05, 06, 07, 08, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 23, 24),
(03, 04, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 23, 24),
(01, 02, 04, 05, 08, 11, 14, 16, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25),
(01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 09, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 22, 25),
(01, 03, 04, 05, 06, 08, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20),
(01, 02, 03, 05, 07, 10, 11, 14, 17, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25),
(01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 09, 13, 14, 16, 20, 22, 23, 24),
(05, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23),
(03, 06, 08, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25),
(01, 03, 07, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21),
(01, 04, 05, 06, 08, 09, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24),
(01, 02, 03, 04, 06, 07, 08, 11, 14, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23),
(01, 02, 03, 04, 09, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25),
(01, 02, 04, 06, 07, 09, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 22, 23),
(01, 02, 05, 07, 08, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24),
(01, 02, 04, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23),
(01, 04, 05, 06, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25),
(01, 04, 05, 07, 08, 10, 11, 14, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24),
(01, 03, 04, 05, 08, 09, 10, 11, 13, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24),
(01, 02, 03, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 22, 24, 25),
(02, 07, 08, 09, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24),
(01, 02, 05, 07, 08, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 24),
(02, 03, 04, 09, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25),
(01, 03, 04, 05, 06, 08, 11, 12, 14, 15, 17, 21, 22, 24, 25),
(01, 03, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 14, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24),
(03, 04, 05, 06, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 18, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25),
(01, 02, 03, 05, 07, 09, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25),
(01, 02, 04, 05, 06, 08, 10, 11, 14, 18, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25),
(01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 08, 10, 11, 13, 15, 18, 20, 22, 25),
(02, 05, 06, 07, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23),
(02, 04, 05, 06, 08, 11, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24),
(01, 02, 03, 06, 07, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25);
```

so you can create query to match each column with the input number

```
SELECT * FROM lotto_table WHERE
   n1=$num1 AND
   n2=$num2 AND
   ....
   ....
   n11=$num11 AND
   n12=$num12;
```

or create a PHP loop for each input number and concat operation to build the query string programatically

Answer (score 1):

Don't store the numbers that way, use a separate row for each number, and make `numeros` integer data type.

Then a simple `GROUP BY` query will give you your answer.

So, your first row of data would instead be:

```
id    number
3    1
3    4
3    6
3    7
3    8
3    9
3    10
3    11
3    12
3    14
3    16
3    17
3    20
3    23
3    24
```

and an example query would be:

```
select id
from lotto_table
where number in (1,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,16,17)
group by id
having count(*) = 12
```

Comment: If I put 'numeros' separatted, can you suggest the search.php file?

Comment: the total of draws are 816. I make a database separating every number in to a row. In that case, the table have 16 rows: id, ball1, ball2, etc...

Answer (score 1):

The sql should be this?

```
(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 18, 20, 23, 24, 25),
(2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20, 23, 24),
(3, 1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 20, 23, 24),
(4, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 23, 24, 25),
(5, 1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20, 23, 24, 25),
(6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 15, 16, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25),
(7, 1, 4, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25),
(8, 1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 25),
(9, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 24, 25),
(10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 19, 20, 23, 24),
(11, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 16, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25),
(12, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 24, 25),
(13, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 23),
(14, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25),
(15, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25),
(16, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25),
(17, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21),
(18, 2, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24),
(19, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 23, 24),
(20, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 23, 24),
(21, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 11, 14, 16, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25),
(22, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 22, 25),
(23, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20),
(24, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 11, 14, 17, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25),
(25, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 13, 14, 16, 20, 22, 23, 24),
(26, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23),
(27, 3, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25),
(28, 1, 3, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21),
(29, 1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24),
(30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 14, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23),
(31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25),
(32, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 22, 23),
(33, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24),
(34, 1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23),
(35, 1, 4, 5, 6, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25),
(36, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 14, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24),
(37, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24),
(38, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 22, 24, 25),
(39, 2, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24),
(40, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 24),
(41, 2, 3, 4, 9, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25),
(42, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 11, 12, 14, 15, 17, 21, 22, 24, 25),
(43, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24),
(44, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 18, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25),
(45, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25),
(46, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 14, 18, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25),
(47, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 18, 20, 22, 25),
(48, 2, 5, 6, 7, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23),
(49, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 11, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24),
(50, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25),
```

The search form that I have is:

```
<?php
mysql_connect ("localhost", "user","pass")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("database");

$num1 = $_POST['num1'];
$num2 = $_POST['num2'];
$num3 = $_POST['num3'];
$num4 = $_POST['num4'];
$num5 = $_POST['num5'];
$num6 = $_POST['num6'];
$num7 = $_POST['num7'];
$num8 = $_POST['num8'];
$num9 = $_POST['num9'];
$num10 = $_POST['num10'];
$num11 = $_POST['num11'];
$num12 = $_POST['num11'];

$sql = mysql_query("select * from lotto_table where numbers like '%$num1%' AND numbers like '%$num2%' AND numbers like '%$num3%' AND numbers like '%$num4%' AND numbers like '%$num5%' AND numbers like '%$num6%' AND numbers like '%$num7%' AND numbers like '%$num8%' AND numbers like '%$num9%' AND numbers like '%$num10%' AND numbers like '%$num11%' AND numbers like '%$num12%'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo 'Game: '.$row['id'];
    echo '<br/> Numbers: '.$row['numbers'];
    echo '<br/><br/>';
    }

?>
```